# What would be the angular momentum of one body (individually) in a two-body problem? Given that only masses and distance between them is known

Tags: angular-momentum, coordinate-systems, orbital-motion, inertial-frames, celestial-mechanics

Considering equation of motion:

$$L = m r^2 \dot{\theta}$$

is constant [angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum). Also see [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/angular-momentum-in-polar-coordinates.715068/).

What would it be for two body problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are permitted to chose any arbitrary axis of rotation and calculate the total moment of inertia (MoI) as:

\begin{equation}
I = \sum_{i}I_{i}
\end{equation}

where $I_{i}$ is the MoI of the $i^\text{th}$ body. It may be more useful to calculate the total MoI around a certain axis, for example around an axis at the midpoint between the two bodies. If the two bodies are point masses and the length between them is $l$ then the total MoI is:

$$I = m_{1}\left(\frac{l}{2}\right)^2 + m_{2}\left(\frac{l}{2}\right)^2$$

$$= (m_{1} + m_{2}) \ \frac{l^{2}}{4}$$

Alternatively, if there are external forces and one wishes to use the conservation of angular momentum in a problem, then it may be more useful to calculate the MoI around an axis such that no external torque acts on the system. However, the choice of the axis of rotation is generally dependent on the context of the problem.